# mkvirtualenv: Too many levels of symbolic links

Tags: virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am running [virtualenv burrito](https://github.com/brainsik/virtualenv-burrito) and getting an error that there are too many levels of symbolic links. I have no idea what that means.

```
mkvirtualenv --python /usr/local/bin/Python3 mantis
```

Error:

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/Python3
Using base prefix '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4'
New python executable in mantis/bin/Python3
Also creating executable in mantis/bin/python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/croberts/.venvburrito/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2352, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/croberts/.venvburrito/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 825, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/Users/croberts/.venvburrito/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 985, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
  File "/Users/croberts/.venvburrito/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1439, in install_python
    raise e
  File "/Users/croberts/.venvburrito/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1431, in install_python
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 1457, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
OSError: [Errno 62] Too many levels of symbolic links
```

I was getting this error before and solved it by doing Python3.4 instead of Python3. Now it won't work no matter which python I try to use. Even if I try to use the default (2.7)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason this wasn't working was because I was capitalizing Python. As soon as I did it using `python3` instead of `Python3` I stopped getting trouble.

Answer (score 40):

Strangely, I ran into this when I tried to create a virtualenv with a name that already existed. Solution to remove the old and create a new one:

```
rmvirtualenv old-one
mkvirtualenv new-one
```

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem on OSX.

I got rid of it after:

```
1. removing env folder
2. removing __pycache__ folder
```

Comment: THanks! this finally saved me from this ordeal

Comment: `rm -rf ${virtualEnvName}` was enough to fix this for my case.

Comment: where are you doing this? I mean in which directory?

Answer (score 6):

I'm using a mac and I solved this by `rm` the virtual env that is named the same as you are trying to create. Specifically, I `rm` the folder within `Users/user_name/.virtualenvs/`. Then the create worked.

Comment: Thanks, I had same issue on Mac which I resolve with your solution

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why but using

```
python3 -m venv venv
```

instead of

```
virtualenv -p python3 venv
```

and then activating the venv or setting the paths manually, something like this

```
      export PYTHONPATH=.:\$PYTHONPATH
      VIRTUAL_ENV=`pwd`/venv
      export VIRTUAL_ENV
      PATH="\$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:\$PATH"
      export PATH
```

worked for me.

I tried to do some quick searching of the different between `virtualenv` and `python3 -m venv` module...but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I came across it after I had built my freshest environment. Because it has been interrupted by myself while it was building the new one. Then I noticed that virtualenvwrapper already created a new environment folder underneath the environment directory but it has not been accomplished properly. Hence, I deleted the lastest environment folder and retried to install same environment. It fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in raspberry pi during open cv installation.
I solve my problem by using below method.

Go to /home/pi
ls -all and check weather .virtualenvs is there or not
if it is there remove it by
rm -r .virtualenvs

Answer (score -1):

File "/Users/croberts/? seems you're using Windows. Consider using ['virtualenvwrapper-win'](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper-win). The latest version is 1.2.0 which support python 2 up to 3.4. I've used it without any problems. If you use several versions of python on your computer, you can switch between them using ['pywin'](https://github.com/davidmarble/pywin).

For making new virtualenv:

```
C:\Users\your_directory>mkvirtualenv neo
Using base prefix 'C:\\Python34'
New python executable in neo\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
```

For view existing virtualenv:

```
C:\Users\your_directory>lsvirtualenv

dir /b /ad "C:\Users\your_directory"
=========================================================================
env0
env1
env2
neo
```