# How to fix 'Too many levels of symbolic links' error in virtualenv?

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

I am getting error(Too many symbolic link levels) while setting up virtual environment in Django web application framework.

I tried to look the following question and answer on stack overflow:

[mkvirtualenv: Too many levels of symbolic links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30040308/mkvirtualenv-too-many-levels-of-symbolic-links)

[virtualenv: Too many levels of symbolic links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334496/virtualenv-too-many-levels-of-symbolic-links)

```
 Kuldeeps-MacBook-Pro:trydjango kuldeep$ pip freeze

  branca==0.3.0
  certifi==2018.8.24
  chardet==3.0.4
  folium==0.6.0+11.g71ab988
  idna==2.7
  Jinja2==2.10
  MarkupSafe==1.0
  numpy==1.15.1
  requests==2.19.1
  six==1.11.0
  urllib3==1.23
  virtualenv==16.1.0

Kuldeeps-MacBook-Pro:trydjango kuldeep$ source bin/activate

(trydjango) Kuldeeps-MacBook-Pro:trydjango kuldeep$ ls

bin     db.sqlite3  include     lib     manage.py   src     trydjango

(trydjango) Kuldeeps-MacBook-Pro:trydjango kuldeep$ pip freeze

-bash: /Users/kuldeep/Dev/trydjango/bin/pip: /Users/kuldeep/Dev/trydjango/bin/python3: bad interpreter: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

ls -l says into *bin* folder:

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 kuldeep  staff    96 Mar 21 21:57 __pycache__ 
-rw-r--r--@ 1 kuldeep  staff  2087 Mar 31 20:19 activate
-rw-r--r--  1 kuldeep  staff  1114 Mar 21 21:56 activate.csh
-rw-r--r--  1 kuldeep  staff  2188 Mar 21 21:56 activate.fish
-rw-r--r--  1 kuldeep  staff  8321 Mar 21 21:56 activate.ps1
-rw-r--r--  1 kuldeep  staff  1143 Mar 21 21:56 activate_this.py
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 kuldeep  staff   290 Mar 21 21:57 django-admin 
-rwxr-xr-x  1 kuldeep  staff   149 Mar 21 21:57 django-admin.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 kuldeep  staff   258 Mar 31 20:08 easy_install
-rwxr-xr-x  1 kuldeep  staff   258 Mar 31 20:08 easy_install-3.7
-rwxr-xr-x  1 kuldeep  staff   240 Mar 31 20:08 pip
-rwxr-xr-x  1 kuldeep  staff   240 Mar 31 20:08 pip3 
-rwxr-xr-x  1 kuldeep  staff   240 Mar 31 20:08 pip3.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 kuldeep  staff     9 Apr 23 10:55 python -> python3.7
-rwxr-xr-x  1 kuldeep  staff  2346 Mar 21 21:56 python-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 kuldeep  staff     9 Apr 23 10:55 python3 -> python3.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 kuldeep  staff     7 Mar 31 20:07 python3.7 -> python3
-rwxr-xr-x  1 kuldeep  staff   236 Mar 31 20:08 wheel
```

[Snapshot of Terminal with -bash Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DU9IN.png)

Comment: Can you provide more information? What steps did you do in your virtualenv so far? pip install anything? Where do the mentioned `pip` and `python3` point to? And where do those references point to, if they are symbolic link? :)

Comment: @ThePjot,  tried to check with pip freeze command without activating virtualenv. After activating virtualenv pip freeze prompts an error of symb links. 
I did not made many steps, just trying to make first django project. pip install was used to install Django.

Comment: Can you run `/Users/kuldeep/Dev/trydjango/bin/python3`? If not what is `ls -lF /Users/kuldeep/Dev/trydjango/bin/python3`?

Comment: how to run /Users/kuldeep/Dev/trydjango/bin/python3? @phd

  `(trydjango) Kuldeeps-MacBook-Pro:trydjango kuldeep$ ls -lF /Users/kuldeep/Dev/trydjango/bin/python3` <br/>

  `lrwxr-xr-x  1 kuldeep  staff  9 Apr 23 10:55 /Users/kuldeep/Dev/trydjango/bin/python3@ -> python3.7`

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem:

```
python3 -> python3.7
python3.7 -> python3
```

`python3` is symlinked to `python3.7`, but `python3.7` is symlinked back to `python3`. This is symlink loop.

I recommend to remove and recreate the virtualenv. Or at least break the loop by removing `python3.7` symlink and linking `python3.7` to the real `python3.7` binary.

Comment: Thanks. How to break the loop?

Comment: `rm python3.7` and thin `ln -s /path/to/real/python3.7`.

Comment: ` . lrwxr-xr-x  1 kuldeep  staff    40 Apr 23 17:22 python3 -> /Users/kuldeep/Dev/trydjango/bin/python3

  lrwxr-xr-x  1 kuldeep  staff    42 Apr 23 17:21 python3.7 -> /Users/kuldeep/Dev/trydjango/bin/python3.7`

did not work! Same at the errror !

Comment: Are `/Users/kuldeep/Dev/trydjango/bin/python3` and `pytho3.7` real pythons or the same files in the same virtualenv? It seems you just created the same loop in a different way.

Comment: removing virtualenv caused permission problems !

Comment: they all are in the same virtualenv.